# How to customize the auth.User Admin page in Django CRUD?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-users

I just want to add the subscription date in the User list in the Django CRUD Administration site.
How can I do that ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I finally did like this in my admin.py file :

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

UserAdmin.list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_active', 'date_joined', 'is_staff')

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: We can also extends the UserAdmin instead of dynamically modifying it !

Comment: To clarify, this should be added to your site's top-level admin.py file.

Comment: can I ask what you mean by top-level?

Comment: It means that you should create an `admin.py` file at the root of your Django project (on the same level as your wsgi.py or settings.py files.)

Comment: It doesn't seem like you need to unregister and reregister

Comment: According to @Carl Meyer on the other answer you need to unregister. How would you do without unregistering?

Comment: using your code above I do get import error as admin is not found

Comment: I think the code organisation may have changed in the last versions of Django.

Comment: No it didn't: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/admin.py

Comment: Maybe you are missing ``from django.contrib import admin`` ?

Comment: This is also asked as "how to make a project admin.py" that might be helpful to people who land here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24128386/admin-py-for-project-not-app/45313274#45313274

Comment: @JamieForrest  In Django 2.1 top-level admin.py file doesn't work. I put it to my own App:(accounts.admin.py) then it works, Don't know why but anyway it works. BTW: There is a full example in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/

Answer (score 24):

Another way to do this is extending the UserAdmin class.

You can also create a function to put on list_display

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserAdmin,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        UserAdmin.list_display = list(UserAdmin.list_display) + ['date_joined', 'some_function']

    # Function to count objects of each user from another Model (where user is FK)
    def some_function(self, obj):
        return obj.another_model_set.count()


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Comment: Can I also do the following (without `__init__`), or is there a problem with it? `class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin): list_display = list(UserAdmin.list_display) + ['date_joined']`

Comment: shouldn't that be `CustomUserAdmin.list_display = ` .. rather than `UserAdmin.list_display = ` ?

Comment: @AmichaiSchreiber I think both works, but I agree that `CustomUserAdmin.list_display = `is the cleaner solution

Answer (score 1):

In admin.py

Import UserAdmin

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
```

Put which fields you need:

```
UserAdmin.list_display = ('email','is_active')  # Put what you need
```

Thats all! It works with Django3

Comment: Or you can extend the `list_display` with additional fields (using Django4): 
`UserAdmin.list_display = list(UserAdmin.list_display) + ['is_active', 'date_joined']`

Answer (score -3):

Assuming that your user class is `User` and your subscription date field is `subscription_date`, this is what you need to add on your `admin.py`

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('subscription_date',)

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: This should inherit from the built-in UserAdmin, otherwise you lose all the rest of the customizations. And you have to unregister the built-in registration too; Natim's answer has the right code.