# Django admin - adding a field to displayed user list

Tags: django-admin, customization

In the Django admin screen for displaying lists of users (with the header, *Select user to change*), there are the fields username/email, etc and staff_status. I would like to add the user's *active* status to that display.

Although most of the django-admin customization questions seem to involve extending the admin model - since this field already *exists*, I would think it only requires changing a template. However, I have looked at all the templates under *admin* and *edit-inline*, and if it's one of those, I can't tell. :)

So how do I add *active* status to the user-list display? A template change, and if so, which one? Note - I'm currently using Django 1.2, not the latest development version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in `http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/admin.py`:

class [`UserAdmin`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L23),

Add it to `list_display` (see [*django doc*](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)):

```
list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff',
                'is_active')
```

Comment: http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.2/django/contrib/auth/admin.py --- it's there also in 1.2 (directly under the auth directory)

Comment: Arg, you're right, sorry - clicked on the wrong directory (sigh).

Comment: The problem with that is that one day you will make an update, and your changes will be gone. Better look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270537/how-to-customize-the-auth-user-admin-page-in-django-crud)

Comment: Please refer to the answer provided by @RafaelSentiesMartielli. That's the proper one!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Worked for me)-

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

UserAdmin.list_display = (....,'is_active')
```