# django 1.3 - can't register my custom UserAdmin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm trying to register a custom User Admin with a memberprofile inline. Based on SO answers and google my `admin.py` looks like:

```
class MemberProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = MemberProfile
    fk_name = 'user'


class FSUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'username',)
    inlines = [MemberProfileInline,]

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, FSUserAdmin)
```

When I load up the admin, none of the changes defined in `FSUserAdmin` take place.
If I comment out

```
admin.site.register(User, FSUserAdmin)
```

I get the error that the user site is not registered, so i know it is getting unregistered successfully.

Does anyone have any insight into what I'm missing?

**update:**
`django.contrib.auth` and `django.contrib.admin` appear before any project specific apps in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list in `settings.py`

I've got the following in my project `urls.py`

```
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
```

Comment: Have you tried the answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270537/how-to-customize-the-auth-user-admin-page-in-django-crud

Comment: do you mean the comment from @JamieForrest of adding it to the site's top level admin.py file?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that this app appears below `contrib.auth` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Comment: all the django contrib apps appear before any of my project specific apps. I didn't bother to post that because i assume if it didn't the call to unregister wouldnt do anything.

Comment: My other suggestion is to make sure you've got [`admin.autodiscover()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#hooking-adminsite-instances-into-your-urlconf) in your urls.py. If you're manually importing the admin modules instead, then perhaps the user admin is not being registered, so there's no need to unregister it! Hope you get it working.

Comment: yes, in the root urls.py i have admin.autodiscover() and i'm not manually importing the admin modules =\. thanks for your suggestions.