# How to set default values for django's User object?

Tags: django, default

I'd like the default value for new users' is_active to be False.  Is there any way to so that prior to creation?   Currently I'm using form_valid to set it on form.instance in my registration view but it seems like there would be an admin setting or something.

Comment: Unregister User and register you modifications, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270537/how-to-customize-the-auth-user-admin-page-in-django-crud

Comment: actually, it might not help you, as the default value is initiated at model level and not form level, see my answer for details

Comment: Is the form written by you or is it a 3rd party form?

Comment: @Arpit It's my form, so no problem with using form_valid(), it just seems like it's an extra overhead during user creation that might be avoided by setting a default in the model itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading into the source code a bit, it seems like is_active is part of the AbstractBaseUser and not even as a field, here's direct code excerpt:

```
class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
    # ...    
    is_active = True
```

It's only later that is_active is turned into a field through another model called AbstractUser:

```
class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # ...
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as '
                    'active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))
```

The User class itself defines almost nothing, really... This whole setup is sursprisingly convoluted, so I think there's no simple way to do it (unless you want to change the source code, which isn't recommended at all). using form_valid sounds like the best approach here.

Comment: I am actually using AbstractUser as my base for my own user object.  Unfortunately attempting to override existing fields in my user generates a field clash error, so that's a no go.

Comment: Sounds like you should use AbstractBaseUser as your base instead. It would prove more flexible and independent, and it's also what the [documentation recommends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model)

Comment: I started writing that way,  but proved to be a pain.  Had to rewrite existing functionality in the manager to change this one setting.