# How to customize Django admin page of Users

Tags: python, django

I was trying to customize Django (version 1.8) admin page of Users (which is under Authentication and Authorization on admin page), but I cannot get it to work.

Currently, the default admin page of Users shows 5 defaults fields: username, email address, first name, last name, staff status. And, I am trying to make the admin Users page show following fields: username, email. date_joined, last_login

So, I created admin.py file and saved it in the directory where wsgi.py is with the following code:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("username", "email", "date_joined", "last_login")
    class Meta:
        model = User

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

But, the code above did not force admin User page display the fields that I want it to display("username", "email", "date_joined", "last_login").

Then, I replaced the code above with the following code in admin.py:

```
class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ("username", "email", "date_joined", "last_login")

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

But, no luck. There was a similar question on stackoverflow and answers to it ([How to customize the auth.User Admin page in Django CRUD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270537/how-to-customize-the-auth-user-admin-page-in-django-crud)), and above two blocks of code are what I was trying to do after reading the answers. But, I still cannot get it to work.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Put admin.py into one of your apps rather then the root directory of your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out what the problem was. The problem was that I did not include the app in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.